# Book or paper recommendation about "Rube Goldberg Mathematics" // e.g. Longest path problems

Tags: graph-theory, computational-complexity, game-theory, book-recommendation

First: My question is not be very specific, since I lack a concrete overview, but my idea/thoughts in a nutshell: I would like to have a recommendation of a good book, paper or article about processes or algorithms that take the longest possible time to solve a certain problem, one example is the longest path problems.

However I would not focus just graph theory, but maybe also other kinds of problems, for example: You have an easy game, for example tic tac toe or much more difficult Chess, and one wants to look what happens, if both players apply Loosing strategies and rules out "loopholes", so that there is actually a progress and change in a game, for example by preventing both players from moving back and forth all the time to avoid a complete standstill.

I am sure, there are many more interesting and more creative questions/problems, which arise by this and I would like to start reading into this field. So I would be very happy, if someone could recommend me an article, book or paper, which approaches those problems on a very easy and non abstract level to understand (for undergraduates is ok, I just want to get a first insight) and also books for further studies. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This seems closely related to the notion of a [busy beaver function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_beaver) and uncomputable functions.

Comment: Do you want to restrict yourself to algorithms that make progress to the solution of a problem? If not, then you could, for instance sort a list of numbers by repeatedly applying a random permutation to the list and checking whether the result is sorted. The expected time to sort this way is clearly $1/n!$ which is fairly inefficient (ahem), though by no means the least efficient way.

Comment: @RickDecker:  There is in your suggested algorithm a further opportunity for inefficiency, namely to check "whether the result is sorted" by an overly elaborate method, e.g. to check whether every possible subset of the list is sorted using bubblesort.

Comment: @hardmath. Indeed there is. Check out [inefficient sorting](http://www.richardhartersworld.com/cri_d/cri/2001/badsort.html) for some stunningly bad examples.

Comment: The [Towers of Hanoi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi) comes to mind as an example where the shortest path is exponentially long.